# Is there a better way to compare two C structs?

Tags: c

Let's assume that I declared a C struct for holding configuration information, which has lots of fields(~30), e.g.:

```
struct config {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    ...
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
    ...
};
```

What is the best way to compare two structs without simply enumerating and comparing each element?
Of course I could use the following code but my question is, is there an easier way to achieve this?

```
static int
cmpInstances(struct config *l, struct config *r) {
    return (
        l->a == r->a &&
        l->b == r->b &&
        l->c == r->c &&
        !strcmp(l->str1, r->str1) &&
        !strcmp(l->str2, r->str2)
    );
}
```

Is there some macro that could do that? For example:
`cmpInstancesViaMacro(a,b,c)` would expand into

```
   l->a == r->a &&
   l->b == r->b &&
   l->c == r->c
```

Comment: You could use `memcmp`, but it will also compare the padding bytes.

Comment: @EugeneSh. And it also won't compare the strings pointed to by `str1`, `str2`, etc, but just the pointer values

Comment: @Kevin That's right, it will be a "shallow" comparison, and probably the pointer values are not something the OP is interested in.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's nothing simpler if you need to compare the targets of pointers.

Comment: Yes, I need to compare them as well. Besides that, I have many different fields inside the struct, for simplicity I omitted some of them from the example above.

Comment: @Kevin But wouldn't the same pointers point to the same memory regions? It is enough for simple scenarios.

Comment: @jtxkopt They would. But the same data might reside in different regions. The OP seem to be interested in comparing the data.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right. I didn't see that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Re: "the same data might reside in different regions". Just to remind: it can be avoided using a hash table. As a result, the same data will have the same address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generalized variant of so-called [X Macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) could be used.

In the example of the question, it would look like this:

```
#define CONFIG_FIELDS \
  X_INT(a) \
  X_INT(b) \
  X_INT(c) \
  X_STRING(str1) \
  X_STRING(str2)

struct config {
  #define X_INT(NAME) int NAME;
  #define X_STRING(NAME) char *NAME;
    CONFIG_FIELDS
  #undef X_INT
  #undef X_STRING
};

static int cmpInstances(struct config *l, struct config *r) {
  #define X_INT(NAME) l->NAME == r->NAME &&
  #define X_STRING(NAME) strcmp(l->NAME, r->NAME) == 0 &&
    return CONFIG_FIELDS 1;
  #undef X_INT
  #undef X_STRING
}
```

With this solution, only the `CONFIG_FIELDS` macro needs to be changed when the structure is changed as long as there is no change to the set of types used. The structure and function would automatically be kept synchronized.

If a new type is introduced, the corresponding X Macros must be defined similar to `X_INT` and `X_STRING` above.

Comment: So if you had a large vocabulary of these, the `#define` sections get replaced by `#include "x-decl.h"` ... `#include "x-undef.h"`, ... `#include "x-compare.h"`, .. `#include "x-undef.h"` and so on.

Comment: @Kaz: I guess you could simply define the `X_INT` and `X_STRING` macros outside the set of `cmpInstances` functions and define them together.

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed, I have updated the answer to use the name CONFIG_FIELDS. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps some macros will help us reduce the lines of code and effort needed:

```c
#define CMP(name) l->name == r->name &&
#define SCMP(name) !strcmp(l->name, r->name) &&

struct config
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    char *str1;
    char *str2;
};

static int cmpInstances(struct config *l, struct config *r) 
{
    return CMP(a) CMP(b) CMP(c) SCMP(str1) SCMP(str2) 1;
}

#undef CMP
#undef SCMP
```

Here we define some macros that take only the name of the variable and compare them. One is written for integer comparison (`CMP`) and the other is written for string comparison (`SCMP`). Then you can use these macros to compare your data and `undef` them when you are done.

Thanks to chqrlie for adding `1` part.

Comment: You should provide a minimum of explanations

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best way to compare two structs without simply enumerating and comparing each element?

The presented way is the best. Except, the pointers should point to `const` - nothing is getting modified.

> is there an easier way to achieve this?

The presented way is the *easiest* way to achieve it, it's also the most readable and self-explanatory, easy to refactor and reason about. Any other will add to complexity and result in maintenance burden.

I find `strcmp(...) == 0` clearer then `!strcmp(...)`.

Comment: For small structures, I agree that plain C code is the best option, but if the structure becomes big it will get harder to check that all elements have been remembered in the compare function. The approach in my answer removes that burden, so if the structure is sufficiently large, I would personally prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

If  you're the author of the struct, you can lay it out so there's no padding, `_Static_assert` that there's no padding (sizeof(whole+struct) == sum of component sizes) and then simply use one `memcmp` call if all the data is in the struct.

If the struct has string pointers (and you can't guarantee that a string with particular contents is stored only in one place), you'll need to do those separately.

You'll get the tightest code if you put all of them next to each other, union-them with a corresponding `char*[]` array, and then loop over the corresponding arrays calling `strcmp` on each pair and combine the result (if all were equal) with memcpy for the rest.

Something like:

```
#include <string.h>
struct config {
    int m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m14,m15,m16;
    union {
        struct { char *s1,*s2,*s3,*s4,*s5,*s6,*s7,*s8; };
        char *strings[8];
    };
};
_Static_assert(sizeof(struct config) == sizeof(int)*16+sizeof(char*)*8,"");

int strings_equal(char *const A[], char *const B[], size_t Count){
    for(;Count;Count--) if(0!=strcmp(*A++,*B++)) return 0;
    return 1;
}
int configs_equal(struct config const *A, struct config const *B){
    return 0==memcmp(A,B,sizeof(int)*16)
        && strings_equal(A->strings,B->strings,sizeof(A->strings)/sizeof(A->strings[0]));
}
```

Comment: `memcmp` the struct won't compare correctly the strings

Comment: @bolov Fixed that.